# List all UNLOGGED tables in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Since version 9.1, PostgreSQL supports the creation of UNLOGGED tables which do not use the WAL and are truncated during any DB recovery. See documentation:  [`create unlogged table`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html)

Where does PostgreSQL store the information, whether a relation is UNLOGGED? I am looking for a query to list all relations that are UNLOGGED.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the `relpersistence` column of the pg_class catalog:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-class.html

Answer (score 8):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html

```
select relname, relowner from pg_class where relpersistence='u';
```